# Google Map not working: Classnotfound Exception

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, classnotfoundexception

I have created the Google Map Marker Sample project using Google SDK , Eclipse. when it comes to the execution, the bin file seems cannot help me install correctly onto the device and make it work. In detail , the Logcat shows the following message:

Class Not found exception error log

```
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267): Process: com.example.testgpsmarker, PID: 25267
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testgpsmarker/com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testgpsmarker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testgpsmarker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testgpsmarker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testgpsmarker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-16 11:25:50.742: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
```

Below is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mc = mapView.getController();
        int latitude = 22285520 ;
        int longitude = 114157690;

        showLocation(latitude,longitude);
    }

    private Handler h = new Handler(){

        // Invoked by the method onTap()
        // in the class CurrentLocationOverlay
        @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle data = msg.getData();

            // Getting the Latitude of the location
            int latitude = data.getInt("latitude");

            // Getting the Longitude of the location
            int longitude = data.getInt("longitude");

            // Show the location in the Google Map
            showLocation(latitude,longitude);
        }
    };

    protected void showLocation(int latitude, int longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            // Getting the MapController
            MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

            // Getting Overlays of the map
            List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

            // Getting Drawable object corresponding to a resource image
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

            // Creating an ItemizedOverlay
            TouchedLocationOverlay locationOverlay = new TouchedLocationOverlay(drawable,h);

            // Getting the MapController
            MapController mc = mapView.getController();

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                                  latitude,
                                  longitude
                             );

            // Locating the point in the Google Map
            mc.animateTo(p);

            // Creating an OverlayItem to mark the point
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(p, "Item", "Item");

            // Adding the OverlayItem in the LocationOverlay
            locationOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

            // Clearing the overlays
            overlays.clear();

            // Adding locationOverlay to the overlay
            overlays.add(locationOverlay);

            // Redraws the map
            mapView.invalidate();

    }
```

\

Layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:apiKey="sdsdfsdfscdsfsdf" />
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testgpsmarker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testgpsmarker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Which configuration should I correct ?

Comment: paste your xml and manifest too.

Comment: Need the layout file and the manifest. Please post it so that it's easier to determine the issue.

Comment: also full code of activity including imports.

Comment: To fix this issue right-click your `project, properties, build path and go to export tab`. There, make sure `"Android private libraries"` are checked. A clean and rebuild should put you on track ...

Comment: OR `Right click on your project and select properties. The "Properties for " panel will open. From the menu on the left go to Java Build Path -> Order and Export` . From the list below uncheck the box next to `"Android Dependencies"`. Finally clean your project and run.